# QGIS 1.8 compiled against PyQt 4.8+?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I'm currently running QGIS on Win7 64bit. My installation says it was compiled against and running against PyQt 4.7.1, although according to the Osgeo4W installer and PyQt4.QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR, I actually have PyQt 4.8.3 installed under the Osgeo4w directory.

I'm running into a bug in my PyQt code (related to QNetworkAccessManager) that, according to the bug tracking log, was fixed in PyQt 4.8.0. It seems, then, that the PyQt 4.7.1 module is being used, and the 4.8.3 module is being ignored. I'd like to resolve this issue.

I've seen a few posts on various forums that suggest that the generic distribution of QGIS 1.8 is compiled against PyQt 4.8. I've tried reinstalling QGIS using the Osgeo4w installer after removing all references to PyQt from my system path, but I still end up with QGIS compiled and running against PyQt 4.7.1.

Could anyone shed some light on this issue for me?

Should QGIS 1.8 installed through Osgeo indeed be a distribution compiled against PyQt 4.8+?

That is, am I doing something wrong in the installation process?

Or will I need to compile QGIS manually if I want it to be compiled against PyQt 4.8?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that QGIS (1.8 and 1.9) are using QT 4.7.1 however the python environment included with QGIS is using PyQT 4.8.3.

Any QGIS API functionality will be implemented using QT 4.7, while code running in python will have access to PyQT 4.8.

Would this explain the behaviour you are experiencing?  If so you might need to reimplement some of the qgis api using PyQT.